# why are extensions available on command line but not in script delivered by nginx?

Tags: php, bcmath

Im running nginx/php-fpm server in a docker container and I added an extension with

```
> docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

bcmath functions are available on command line but not in script

i.e. this works:

```
> bash-4.4# php -r "echo bcdiv('105', '6.55957', 3);"
result=16.007
```

but this fails

```
// test.php
<?php
echo bcdiv('105', '6.55957', 3);  // 16.007
?>
```

when delivered as

```
http://test-server/test.php
```

the result (in the browser) =

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bcdiv() in /var/www/html/web/test.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/web/test.php on line 3
```

Why can the command line see the extension, but the script can't? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably have two ini files. One for CLI the other for php-fpm. My guess you need to uncomment the line in your php-fpm configuration to enable the module. Add a `phpinfo()` to your test.php and see what it shows you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Restarting nginx (in my case) was not sufficient. I had to restart php-fpm for changes to take effect. Result: works ok.